# How to get a variable from inside a method

Tags: php, class, variables, global-variables, scope

If I have a file `class.php`:

```
class Greeting {
   function Hello {
      $variable = 'Hello World!';
   }
}
```

And then a main file `index.php`:

```
include('class.php');
$page = new Greeting();
$page->Hello();
```

How can I access the contents of `$variable` inside of `index.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant access it as it stands now. You would need to make it a property like:

```
class Greeting {
   public $variable = 'Hello World!';
   function Hello {
      return $this->variable;
   }
}
```

Then you can access it like:

```
$page = new Greeting();
echo $page->variable;
// or
echo $page->Hello();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to not overlook all the possibilities, you can also do:

```
class Greeting {
   function Hello() {
      global $variable;
      $variable = 'Hello World!';
   }
}

$page = new Greeting();
$page->Hello();

echo $variable;
```

But don't do it! It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, make `$variable` public in the class itself and then set it in the Hello() function.

```
class Greeting {
   public $variable = '';

   function Hello {
      $this->variable = 'Hello World!';
   }
}
```

Then you can retrieve it by doing:

```
include('class.php');
$page = new Greeting();
$page->Hello();
echo $page->variable;
```

Another alternative would be to make Hello() return the $variable, and then you could retrieve it from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
     class Greeting {
 public $variable = 'Hello World!';
 function Hello (){
    echo $this->variable;
 }
}
$page = new Greeting();
$page->Hello();
```